# How to list container image versions in the Google private Container Registry

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-container-registry

I can use `gcloud docker search gcr.io/my-project` to list the images published in `my-project` in the Google private Container Registry.

```
NAME                              DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
my-project/gabipetrovay-service                 0                    
my-project/jillix-service                       0                    
my-project/service                              0
```

How can I see the versions available for these images?

`gcloud docker inspect gcr.io/my-project/gabipetrovay-service` will describe only the images that have been pulled. What I want is to see what versions a certain image has published in the Container Registry.

Answer (score 4):

Docker doesn't really expose a good way to do this via the CLI.

You can hit the API directly:

```
curl -u _token:$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
  https://gcr.io/v2/my-project/jillix-service/tags/list
```

We (GCR) have some proprietary extensions, but `tags: [...]` is a standard part of the message, which is (I believe) what you are looking for.